# Using async functions as conditions

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Lets say i want to run an if statment where the condition is async function.

```
const con = require('./con');

if(con.con('email@gmail.com')
  console.log('User exists!')
else {
  console.log('user does not exist?')
}
```

This is the function, it uses mongoose findOne which is an async task.

```
const User = require ('../nodeDB/models/user.js');

const con = function (email) {
     User.findOne( { userEmail: email }, function (err, doc) {
       if(err) {
           console.log(err);
       }
       
       if (doc) {
           return false;
       } else {
           return true;
       }
     });
}

module.exports.con = con;
```

The problem is that the if statment gets called before the con can get executed which then does'nt set the condition.

Comment: Are you using async/await?

Comment: use await, or put your if in the 'then' block after you call the function.

Comment: tried adding async and await but then it gives the error ```MongooseError: Query was already executed: User.findOne({ userEmail: 'email@gmail.com' })```havent tried putting the if in a then block but which if do you mean. also thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way :

```
const con = userEmail => User.findOne({userEmail}).lean().exec();

(async () => {
    if (await con('email@gmail.com')) {
        console.log('User exists!')
    } else {
        console.log('user does not exist?')
    }
})()
```

1. Return `User.findOne` from your function.

(optional) 2. Add it `.lean()` (returns simple JSON, faster)

(optional) 3. Add it `.exec()` so it returns a true Promise and not just a thenable

4. now you can simply `await con()` anywhere inside an `async` function, just as if it was synchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your `con()` function doesn't return anything. You will need to `return User.findOne(....)`

Your if statement needs to respect the fact that the async task has to complete first.

```js
con.con('email@gmail.com')
  .then((exists) => {
     if (exists)
       console.log('User exists!')
     else {
       console.log('user does not exist?')
     }
  })
```

Or with `aynsc`/`await`:

```js
async function checkIfUserExists() {
  if (await con.con('email@gmail.com')
    console.log('User exists!')
  else {
    console.log('user does not exist?')
  }
}
```

Comment: Also you have to `return User.findOne()` from `con()`. Currently it doesn't return anything.

Comment: @JeremyThille yikes good point

Answer (score 1):

Use `await` or put your logic in `then` block.

```js
// must be in async declared function
if (await foo()) {
}
else {
}

// or 

foo().then(res=>{
  if (res) {
  }
  else {
  }
})
```

Comment: Also you have to `return User.findOne()` from `con()`. Currently it doesn't return anything.

Comment: @JeremyThille That is why i simply answered op's question, and did not reference their call to con().  2 issues :)